How can I add a window to my app from a button in a menu bar?
I would like to make something like the following work:
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestWindowApp: App {
  init() {
    _showWindow = .constant(false)
  }

  var body: some Scene {

    MenuBarExtra {
      Button("Show window") { showWindow = true }
    } label: {
      Text(">_<")
    }

    if showWindow {
      Window("window", id: "main") {
        Text("Hello, SwiftUI!")
          .padding()
      }
    }
  }

  @Binding
  var showWindow: Bool
}

This doesn't compile.
I tried using WindowGroup instead of Window which compiles if the condition is in the WindowGroup. I first found WindowGroup to work unreliably when MenuBarExtra is present, and when it works it shows an empty window when the showWindow condition is not satisfied:
WindowGroup {
  if showWindow {
    Text("Hello, SwiftUI!")
      .padding()
  }
}

I'm quite confident I could get the desired behavior with creating an NSWindow when showWindow is true, but I would prefer not mixing AppKit with SwiftUI.

Use the openWindow environment value to open a window. You should not surround the window with an if.
@Environment(\.openWindow) var openWindow

var body: some Scene {
    MenuBarExtra {
        Button("Show window") { openWindow(id: "main") }
    } label: {
        Text(">_<")
    }
    Window("window", id: "main") {
        Text("Hello, SwiftUI!")
            .padding()
    }
}

By writing the MenuBarExtra first, the window will not be initially open.
Window is only one window. Clicking on the menu button a second time will not open a second window. If you want that behaviour, use a WindowGroup, which can open the same window multiple times.
